# IntelliJ: how can I open an editor with inline warnings looking like in code lens?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

IntelliJ: how can I make an editor tab open with code lens mode with inline warnings etc. looking like in code lens hover view?

I imagine a hotkey to toggle between code lens like editor and default editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA 14.